# Easy alternation between different Java version installation

Tags: macos, java

I currently have `Java 6` installed on my system (please don't laugh) and we are moving to `Java 8`. So we have changed the main branch of our application to use Java 8, however, we need to support old versions that run on Java 6. So we need to easily alternate.

I understand that `java` (command) points to `/usr/bin/java`, which is a symlink to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`.  That directory looks as follows:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions@16:44:32>ls -la
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Jun 16 16:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel  408 Jun 16 16:43 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jun 16 16:39 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jun 16 16:39 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jun 16 16:39 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jun 16 16:39 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jun 16 16:39 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jun 16 16:39 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 Jun 16 16:43 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 Jun 16 16:39 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 Jun 16 16:39 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

I can install Java 8 without uninstalling Java 6 and would like to have a mechanism of easily repointing the related commands in /usr/bin from `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents` to `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents`.

Is there a quick and existing way of doing it as opposed to writing my own script when I have to go to legacy branches/versions of our app for troubleshooting and PROD support? Like flip the java alternative from 6 to 8 and it does it all for you.

Comment: Don't laugh at Java 6! It's the only Java my Snow Leopard server can run. ;)

Comment: 1) Did you try changing versions from the command line: java -version:< version number >. 2) Is it possible for your purposes to use java from the command line, you could set the old JVM with PATH.